# Path in a $(6\times 3)$ rectangle

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

> In the following grid (where each  movement is either $1$ step rightward or $1$ step upward) find the number of paths from $P$ to $Q$, if the path between $R$ and $S$ is deleted.

(figure below)

[image]

**My Trial**: If the route $(R\rightarrow S)$ is connected, then the number of routes from $P$ to $Q$ is $$\left(P\rightarrow Q\right) = \displaystyle \binom{10}{3} \tag{I}$$

Now if $(R\rightarrow S)$ is missing, then the number of paths from $P$ to $Q$ is $$(P\rightarrow Q) = (P\rightarrow R)\times (R\rightarrow S) = \displaystyle \binom{5}{2}\times \binom{4}{1}$$

But the answer given is 
$$\displaystyle \binom{10}{3}-\binom{5}{2}\times \binom{4}{1} \tag{II}$$

I do not understand why we substract $(I)-(II)$.

Thanks.

Comment: If $R \to S$ is missing and cannot be used, then you want to count all paths from $P$ to $Q$ *except for* those including the edge $R \to S$, right? So to count these paths, you could count *all* paths, and subtract those paths that do use the edge $R \to S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you calculated the number of paths from P to Q which necessarily pass through the R-S edge. that is $ \displaystyle \binom{5}{2}\times \binom{4}{1}$.

However, those paths are exactly the ones we don't wish to count.
Hence, since we know the total number of paths is $ \binom{10}{3}$
we can conclude the number of the paths which posses our required property is

$$\displaystyle \binom{10}{3}-\binom{5}{2}\times \binom{4}{1}$$